# Save multiple table objects in single array using ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have on table with 3 colums.There is no `required` field in my table.

when I click on save button each row should be save as separate object in a single array.

1.If document is not uploaded ,that can be empty.
2.checkbox is checked it should be `true` otherwise `false`. 
3.But Name should be in each object.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.listName = [{
            'name': 'aaa'
        },{
            'name': 'bbb'
        },{
            'name': 'ccc'
        }];
    $scope.saveDetails = function(doc) {
        if ($('#status').is(':checked')) {
            doc.status = 'true'
        } else {
            doc.status = 'false'
        }
        console.log(doc)
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>file</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='doc in listName'>
                <td>{{doc.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" ng-model="doc.file" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="doc.status" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="saveDetails(doc)">save</button>
</div>
```

Any help?Thanks!!

Comment: `('#status').is(':checked')` should be `$('#status').is(':checked')`

Comment: @manikantgautam updated.Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to jquery methods 
try follwing:

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.listName = [{
            'name': 'aaa',
             file: "",
            status:false
        },{
            'name': 'bbb',
             file: "",
            status:false
        },{
            'name': 'ccc',
             file: "",
            status:false
        }];
    $scope.saveDetails = function(doc) {
        
        console.log($scope.listName)
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>file</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='doc in listName'>
                <td>{{doc.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" ng-model="doc.file" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="doc.status" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button ng-click="saveDetails(doc)">save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I can directly print full array.But please read my question once again.I want to uploaded files and checkbox value dynamically.